# i need to generate ansible-playbook using jinja2 with csv file in ansible

Tags: csv, group, ansible

i need to create jinja templates to generate ansible playbook for that i need to read datas from csv file

csv file is similar to below(file name ansi.csv)

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
aa01,ansi,directory,yes
aa02,jinj,directory,yes
aa01,play,direvtory,yes
aa02,tem,directory,yes
```

and my playbook to generate template is

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    csvfile: "{{ lookup('file', 'csv_files/ansi.csv')}}"
  tasks:
  - name: generate template
    template:
       src: template.j2
       dest: playbook.yml
```

and i have created template like bellow

```
---
{% for item in csvfile.split("\n") %}
{% if loop.index != 1 %}
{%   set list = item.split(",") %}
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: {{ list[0]|trim()}}
  become: {{ list[3]}}
  tasks:
  - name: {{ list[1] }}
    file:
      path: {{list[1]}}
      state: {{ list[2] }}
{%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

out put playbook i'm getting is something simler to bellow

```
---
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: ansi
    file:
      path: ansi
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa02
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: jinj
    file:
      path: jinj
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: play
    file:
      path: play
      state: directory
- name: make directory
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: tem
    file:
      path: tem
      state: directory
```

but need to get playbook like bellow

```
---
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: ansi
    file:
      path: ansi
      state: directory

  - name: play
    file:
      path: play
      state: directory

- name: make directory
  hosts: aa02
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: jinj
    file:
      path: jinj
      state: directory

  - name: tem
    file:
      path: tem
      state: directory
```

in above playbook my expectation is to group by 1st column and only i have to repeat tasks section(if hosts are same), can some one help me to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: To create a directory the parameter `state` shall be *directory* not *yes*. Right? Fix the question.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ddd` parameter then? `become`, perhaps?

Comment: thank you @VladimirBotka i mistakenly gave yes instated of directory, and become is for execute as sudo user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the csv file with the module [read_csv](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/read_csv_module.html#read-csv-read-a-csv-file) and use the filter [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#groupby). For example the playbook and the template below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - read_csv:
        path: ansi.csv
      register: data
    - template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: playbook.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat template.j2
---
{% for host in data.list|groupby('aaa') %}
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: {{ host.0 }}
  become: yes
  tasks:
{% for task in host.1 %}
    - name: {{ task.bbb }}
      file:
        path: {{ task.bbb }}
        state: {{ task.ccc }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

give

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml 
---
- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa01
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: ansi
      file:
        path: ansi
        state: directory

    - name: play
      file:
        path: play
        state: direvtory

- name: 'make directory'
  hosts: aa02
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: jinj
      file:
        path: jinj
        state: directory

    - name: tem
      file:
        path: ten
        state: directory
```

Comment: Thank a lot @Vlandimir Botka. Your answer was helful.